# What does an "X" in a black circle in the status bar mean?

Tags: jailbreak, ios

Just to the left of my battery percentage, there is a x inside of a circle in the status bar. I've never seen this before and was hoping someone could explain this! Thank you!

Edit: Here is an screenshot: [image: Here is an screenshot:]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a screenshot of what you're seeing.  Many app add icons to the status bar and a picture will increase your chances at getting a good answer.

Comment: @fbara Image is up now.

Comment: Is your iPhone jailbroken?  Have you gone through `Settings` and looked for anything turned off?  I ask because I don't recall seeing that icon for any of the default settings.  Do you have GPS turned off?

Comment: Yes, it has been for a couple of weeks now. But no, I do not see any settings switched off. This popped up, if I recall correctly, just after installing a theme for my device.

Comment: That's important info to have in your question.  I'll add a tag for 'jailbreak'.  Hopefully, someone will be able to help you because I don't know anything about jailbroken iPhones.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us what tweaks you have loaded up on Cydia. This is not a regular iOS status bar icon, so it must be from one of the loaded tweaks.

Comment: Possibly there is something corresponding to the icon in your Notifications. Anything interesting in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, but thank you to everyone for your help! I found the problem was a theme installed called 'Veexillum' and the actual icon is just orientation lock! Thanks again to everyone!